# What is a "noninvasive" biomarker for a disease?

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics

What is a "noninvasive" biomarker for a disease? I know what a biomarker is, but what makes it noninvasive?

Comment: The term "non-invasive" probably refer to the sampling method rather than the nature of the biomarker. One would probably need the original paper and citation where you found this term in order to answer the question.

Comment: There are tons of papers that use this term, and none that I had a look define this term. All those papers as well as Wikipedia assume the readers already know what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A biomarker, or biological marker, generally refers to a measurable indicator of some biological state or condition. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biomarker)

The presence of certain 'things' (sorry for being vague) in a tissue obtained invasively - via biopsy, for example - are considered biomarkers for, say, a cancer. It could be histopathological - a particular abnormality seen on staining the tissue - or it could be the presence or absence of a membrane receptor, etc.

A non-invasive biomarker is simply one that can be obtained easily and without "harm" to the (patient?), for example, to identify the potential presence of a cancer without the need for a biopsy. (Obviously, this doesn't eliminate the need for invasive methods. It just adds to the arsenal of detection methods.)

That is the usual meaning of non-invasive biomarker in the many, many papers using the term (at least medically), such as the one cited.

<sub>[Serum microRNAs as non-invasive biomarkers for cancer](http://molecular-cancer.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1476-4598-9-306)</sub>

Comment: Although one could argue that a blood draw is still invasive. I use the term non-invasive to refer to things like the presence of lumps in a cancerous breast (something that can be palpated) or the yellow-tinged eyes and skin correspondent with various diseases of the liver, that sort of thing.

Comment: @MattDMo - There are biomarkers that don't involve venipuncture (like exhaled substances), but the literature doesn't use the term like you do, as evidenced by the thousands (literally) of papers about them.

Comment: So a biomarker in the blood is non-invasive? Hmm. I'll have to chat with my colleagues about that...

Comment: @MattDMo - Please do. Serum biomarkers are considered non-invasive when the gold standard is an invasive study. Again, I can cite you papers that use it in this way (see the one cited in my answer, for example.)

Comment: No, that's fine, I believe you. I just want to make sure the rest of my team and some of my senior colleagues in the department all think the same way (I'm guessing they do), because I've somehow missed picking up on that in my reading. TIL :)

Comment: So even something like a leukopak is non-invasive, but a needle/punch biopsy is invasive? I'm just wondering where the line is. I'm guessing it's whether or not *solid* tissue is removed...

Comment: @MattDMo - Needle biopsy is considered an invasive study. I think the difference *is* that an invasive study obtains a tissue sample. A buccal swab, however, is considered by many - but not all - as non-invasive, even though tissue is obtained (others call it "minimally invasive".) So, TIL, as well. Thanks. :)